# Python import: AttributeError: module 'unittest' has no attribute 'mock'

Tags: python, unit-testing, import, mocking

If I import unittest and use mock the following error message is shown:
AttributeError: module 'unittest' has no attribute 'mock'

This occurs with:

```py
import unittest

with unittest.mock.patch( ...
```

If I change the code as follows the error does not appear:

```py
from unittest import mock

with mock.patch( ...
```

Why is it necessary to use from ... import ...?

I'm using Python 3.7.3

Comment: Importing a package does not automatically load its submodules.

Comment: Thank you for your great explanation in the linked answer :)